# Backslash When Using Apostrophe In Textarea

Tags: character-encoding

I have an invite a friend form on this page: http://backtochurch.com/emailafriend/friends

I have a textarea with some pre-filled text with the word "it's" in the last line. The apostrophe keeps getting encoded in the sent email with a backslash in front of the apostrophe.

I am using ExpressionEngine and Magic Quotes is off

I have tried using:

```
\\\' &#146; &apos;
```

I have searched for an answer on this, but none of these solutions work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more about the textarea field? How you've configured it in EE? What is Default Text Formatting set to?

Comment: Is it stored to the database with the slashes, and then e-mailed, or emailed out directly?

Comment: It's email directly. I also just sent myself a test on my iphone and it looks fine. The slash so far is showing up in gmail and Outlook

Comment: Everything is handled on this page. Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/steveeller/WhVuv/

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I know you said `magic_quotes_gpc` is set to off? You verified that by checking the `phpinfo()`. I see that you have `Mail.php` and `db_class.php` includes. Is it possible the field data is passing through an `addslashes()` call in a function call from one of those?

Comment: Maybe the mail library you use is adding slashes. have you looked at the raw message source in your mail client? Also why not use CodeIgniter (which is part of EE) for form-validation and sending the emails. (ps. you expose your password in the example fiddle)